# Класс принимающий массив

Tags: c++, классы, класс

Я написал класс, который принимает комплексное число и выводит его действительную и мнимую части.

```
#include <iostream>
class Complex {

private:
    double r, m; // x = Re + Im*i 
public:
    Complex(double nr = 0, double nm = 0) : r(nr), m(nm) { }
    double& operator[] (int index);
};


double& Complex::operator[] (int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return r;
    }
    if (index == 1) {
        return m;
    }
}
void main() {

    Complex b(2, 6);

    Complex d = b[0];
    Complex e = b[1];

}
```

Теперь хочу, чтобы он принимал гиперкомплексное число, т. е например число b(2,[1,2,3,4,5]). В private я так полагаю нужно сделать double r, m[5]. Что делать дальше?

```
#include <iostream>
class Complex {

private:
    double r, m[5]; // x = Re + Im*i 
public:
    Complex(double nr, double nm[5]){
        r = nr;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            m[i] = nm[i];
        }
    }
    double& operator[] (int index);
};


double& Complex::operator[] (int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        return r;
    }
    if (index == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            return m[i];
        }
    }
}
void main() {

    Complex b(2, [1,2,3,4,5]);

    Complex d = b[0];
    Complex e = b[1];

}
```

Comment: А в чем затык? Казалось бы, сделать по аналогии.

Comment: Добавил код. Выдает ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложенный в соседнем ответе `(double[5]){1,2,3,4,5}` - *compound literal* - это фича языка С. Она не работает в С++, но некоторые компиляторы поддерживают ее в качестве нестандартного расширения.

---

Можно написать так:

```
double arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
Complex b(2, arr);
```

Еще стоит заменить параметр на `const double nm[5]`, тогда константные массивы тоже можно будет передавать.

Сразу возникает вопрос, а можно ли написать `Complex b(2, {1,2,3,4,5});`. С вашим классом - нельзя.

В параметрах функций, массивы автоматически заменяются на указатели, т.е. параметр `double nm[5]` превращается в `double *nm`, а инициализировать указатель списком чисел нельзя.

Но такая замена не происходит со ссылками на массивы, поэтому если заменить параметр на `const int (&arr)[5]` - то все будет работать.

Но с таким параметром больше не получится передавать указатель на середину более длинного массива.

Возможно стоит сделать два конструктора, с обоими вариантами параметров.

---

Вот тут глупость написали:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    return m[i];
}
```

Это эквивалентно `return m[0];`. Или возвращайте элементы массива по одному, при `index` = 1..5, или делайте для массива отдельный геттер, возвращающий ссылку на весь массив целиком:

```
const int (&imag())[5]
{
    return m;
}
```

Comment: опять забыл про C++ извраты. остался только вариант с переменной.

Comment: почему `fun((double[5]){1,2,3,4,5})` выдаёт предупреждение `ISO C++ forbids compound-literals`, а `fun({1,2,3,4,5})` - нет ?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Compound literal - это именно `(тип){знач}`.

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис массивов другой (*неоффициальная C поддержка, в плюсах нельзя*):

```
(double[5]){1,2,3,4,5}
```

Сначала представляется тип и размерность, потом всё в фигурных скобках.

Но так как этот массив передаётся только по адресу, а вы передаёте временный объект, то компилятор не предоставляет его адрес. Выходом может служить дополнительная переменная или смена типа аргумента на r-value ссылку.

```
Complex(double nr, double ( && nm )[5]){
..
int main(){
  Complex b(2,(double[5]){1,2,3,4,5}); 
..
```

или

```
int main(){
  double[5] tmp{1,2,3,4,5};
  Complex b(2,tmp); 
  ..
```

*Официально в C++ нельзя делать временный массив, остаётся только второй вариант с дополнительной переменной **tmp**.*